# javascript to check checkbox when input box is ticked - checkbox array []

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, foreach

I have a simple javascript issue. I have a checkbox and a input box.

when the user inputs text into an input box (onkeydown) I want it to check the corresponding checkbox in the row.

My checkbox's all share the same name for an array `checkbox[]`.

my simplified syntax is:

```
<table>
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach ($records as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name="editcustomer[]" id="editcustomer[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customer_name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->customer_name ; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('editcustomer<?php echo $row->id ?>').checked = true;">
        </td>
    <tr>
<?php endforeach ; ?>
</table>
```

As the name of the checkbox is not unique, only the value thereof how do I tell the javascript which checkbox to check?

```
<input type="text" name="customer_name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="customer_name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->customer_name ; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('editcustomer<?php echo $row->id ?>').checked = true;">
```

Help appreciated as always.

Thanks

Comment: call a method on onkeydown / onchange with passing this as a parameter, then in that function use
`function abc(elem)
{
$(this).parent().next().find(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
}`

Comment: can you assist by looking at the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/A4GaF/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"/>
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"/>
<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" />
 <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
<input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$(':text').change(function(){
    $(this).prev(':checkbox').attr('checked','true');
});
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: Hi X-Factor. thanks for your time. not quite working as per fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/A4GaF/1/. any ideas why? how does the script know which checkbox it must find. so on the fiddle, if I type in any box it should check the corresponding checkbox. Thanks

Comment: I updated your code, but you have to add jquery for that @Smudger